# Outlook Search for Folder Name

Tags: vba, outlook, office365, ms-office, outlook-addin

Is there a way to quickly search for the name of a folder in outlooks inbox folder structure?

I am talking about this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cBMc.png

Ideally this would be in the form of a search bar above the folder structure. 
I am asking this because I need to categorize emails into these folders as they arrive.

We are running our own Exchange and I am using Outlook over rdp
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZDKS.png

Comment: [Find a Folder Misplaced in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296811/find-a-folder-misplaced-in-outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to search for a folder. It would be a pretty simple add-in to build too.  I swear they had something like this in Outlook 97 or 2000...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to develop a VBA macro. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

But the Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for placing a search bar on top of the Navigation pane. You need to use Windows API functions to inject your own form with controls anywhere in the Outlook Explorer window. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) and [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) to get started.

Comment: can you be more specific about the macro... the search bar was not a requirement, it was an idealisation

Comment: You need to walk along the folder tree programmatically to find the required folder.

Comment: You need to develop a VBA macro or add-in for Outlook. See my answer for more information. The Folder class provides the Folders property which returns the Folders collection that represents all the folders contained in the specified Folder.